# Python: Brute Force Sudoku Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, sudoku

I am trying to implement a brute-force sudoku solver. I know I am not the first one to try that and that there are multiple resources out there and I have looked at several of them. However, I seem to be unable to solve my problem even after having looked at them -- I know full well what my problem is, I just can't seem to solve it. This is my solver so far:

```
    def solve(self, pos):
        i, j = pos[0], pos[1]

        if i > 8:
            return self.show()
        
        if self.array[i,j] != 0:
            if j < 8:
                return self.solve([i, j+1])
            else:
                return self.solve([i+1,0])
        else:
            for k in range(1, 10):
                if self.check_entry(k, pos):
                    self.assign(k, pos)
                    if j < 8:
                        return self.solve([i, j+1])
                    else:
                        return self.solve([i+1,0])
            else:
                self.array[i,j] = 0
```

My problem is, that the recursion does not work and that is related to the very last else-statement.

The first if just contains the termination conditions: once my indices have moved out of bounds I'm done and returning the sudoku (saved as a 2-dimensional 9 by 9 array).
The second if deals with entries already given by just skipping them and moving on to the next entry (in row if there is room or in the next line if we are at the end of one line).
The corresponding else is of course where the actual work is to be done: The check_entry(self, entry, pos) method checks wether an entry (in this case k) is valid at position pos and if so, I assing k to position pos = [pos[0], pos[1]] in the array. If I exhaust the for-loop without having found a valid candidate, the last line is supposed to set position [i, j] back to 0 and return control to the previous function call (so that it can choose another k for its position and so on...) But that does not happen. Instead, if the the for-loop is exhausted without any valid entry the function call just returns `None` and the previous function calls do anything.

I have been trying to figure out what (if any) return statement I want in that last branch, so that control can be handed to the previous function call and it can choose another k for it's position, but by now I am just kind of stuck.

If someone could be kind enough to point out to me my obvious stupidity and show me what I am missing, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: should'nt you have a `return` in the end statement? Without it you don't jump to the previous function

Comment: I think so, too. But what exactly should I return? I don't think I'm supposed to deepen the recursion by returning another call of `solve` nor am I supposed to call solve on an earlier position (`solve([i, j-1])` oder `solve([i-1,8])`) because these should already be active (not finished yet) and adding another calling would just lead to an infinite recursion. Thats what I meant by saying im kind of stuck...

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. The Problem is returning `None` if the for-loop is exhausted without having found a valid candidate. The solution is not adding another return statement at the end but a condition before:

```
                    if j < 8:
                        solution = self.solve([i, j+1])
                    else:
                        solution = self.solve([i+1,0])
                    if solution is not None:
                        return solution
```

returns control to the previous funtion call as intended by ignoring a subsequent function call (that would otherwise return `None`) and allows the recursion the proceed as inteded.
Is there a way to close the question/to mark as closed/answered?